# Animate markers on Google MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, android-mapview, marker

I am working on an Android app that displays multiple markers on a Google MapView. Everything works perfectly but I would like the markers to have an animation when they appear on the map.

[Here's an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoihGhqyfAE) of something similar on iPhone. See 1'20".

Here is how I add them to my MapView.

```
for(int i=0; i<myMarkerList.length(); i++){
GeoPoint x = new GeoPoint(
                (int)(lat*1E6),
                    (int)(lng*1E6));

        oItem = new OverlayItem(x, title, String.valueOf(nb_marker));
        pin.setAlpha(255);
        oItem.setMarker(pin);           

        if (oItem != null)              
            mapOverlay.addOverlay(oItem); // add the overlay item to the overlay            
        }              
        mapOverlays.add(mapOverlay); // add the overlay to the list of overlays
        mapView.invalidate(); // update the map shown
```

It is so pretty on iPhone, and someone must have already done something similar on Android but I can't seem to find any useful info.

EDIT: Okay so I recon I either have to override the draw method which will be long and not that pretty, or just give up with OverlayItems.

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work using a simple ArrayList of ImageViews and animation on them, no MapOverlay.

Comment: Hi Tom, Can you show me an example how you achieve your problem as I am also looking for the solution. It will be of great help if you can show me an example.

Comment: @TechGeeky hi mate i am stuck with this from last few days but cant find the way...i have a same problem i hope you may succeed on this issue..commenting here with a hope that you may understand my feelings if this solved for me..plzz help thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can  use [this tutorial](http://www.actionshrimp.com/2011/05/speech-bubble-popups-containing-a-view-for-android-mapview/) for a reference, it uses animations, so I think that suits your solution.

Code from the tutorial :

```
//Reference to our MapView
MapView mapView = (MapView) activity.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

//Get a LayoutInflater and load up the view we want to display.
//The false in inflater.inflate prevents the bubble View being added to the MapView straight away
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout bubble = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble, mapView, false);

//Set up the bubble's close button
ImageButton bubbleClose = (ImageButton) bubble.findViewById(R.id.bubbleclose);
bubbleClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ResultsMapResultsDisplayer.this.activity, R.anim.fadeout);
        bubble.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        bubble.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

---

```
private void displaySearchResultBubble(final SearchResult result) {
    //Hide the bubble if it's already showing for another result
    map.removeView(bubble);
    bubble.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Set some view content
    TextView venueName = (TextView) bubble.findViewById(R.id.venuename);
    venueName.setText(result.getName());

    //This is the important bit - set up a LayoutParams object for positioning of the bubble.
    //This will keep the bubble floating over the GeoPoint result.getPoint() as you move the MapView around,
    //but you can also keep the view in the same place on the map using a different LayoutParams constructor
    MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        result.getPoint(), MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);

    bubble.setLayoutParams(params);

    map.addView(bubble);
    //Measure the bubble so it can be placed on the map
    map.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    //Runnable to fade the bubble in when we've finished animatingTo our OverlayItem (below)
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fadein);
            bubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bubble.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        }
    };

    //This projection and offset finds us a new GeoPoint slightly below the actual OverlayItem,
    //which means the bubble will end up being centered nicely when we tap on an Item.
    Projection projection = map.getProjection();
    Point p = new Point();

    projection.toPixels(result.getPoint(), p);
    p.offset(0, -(bubble.getMeasuredHeight() / 2));
    GeoPoint target = projection.fromPixels(p.x, p.y);

    //Move the MapView to our point, and then call the Runnable that fades in the bubble.
    mapController.animateTo(target, r);
 }
```

Comment: Hey Reno, I came across this tutorial when searching for info on Google, but I believe this does not do what I am looking for. There's a fade in animation but it is casted on a Layout and not an OverlayItem like me. I'll try it out anyway. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I seen your example app. From that i think you need only Glow in your markers, right? If yes then its possible through the styles and its having glow property also.

Comment: Hi Scorpion, actually the glow style is optional, the most important thing is the way they appear, they scale with some kind of bouncing effect.