# how to make map marker bounce on Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to make a marker on the MapView bounce? I mean already provided by the mapview (like the web google map).

Or I'll have to write my own code for animation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's been added recently to the Maps API, I believe you'll need to do the animation yourself.  There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180339/animate-markers-on-google-mapview) that may help you.